# nested movie clips

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm having some trouble following [this (link)](http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/games/create-a-pseudo-3d-pong-game/) tutorial. I'm new to flash, so please bear with me.

In step 1 of this tutorial, we have created multiple movie clips and then a single big movie clip(including all the movie clips).

In step 4, I'm not able to access the properties of the clips we created earlier by using the following code, like in the tutorial.

```
         bg.wallTop.rotationX = 90;
         bg.wallBottom.rotationX = -90;
         bg.wallRight.rotationY = 90;
         bg.wallLeft.rotationY = -90;
```

Any clues of what i might be doing wrong? And about the jargon, what do we call this process of accessing inner clips, through outer clips. e.g bg.wallTop

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Automatically declare stage instances turned on (Publish Settings>Flash>Settings)? If not make sure it is.

If that doesn't work, try changing `public class Main` to `public dynamic class Main`.

If that doesn't work, see if `var bg:MovieClip = MovieClip(getChildByName("bg"))` works.

If you're still stuck, we'll need to see more code.

Answer (score 0):

The source files they give you already have a bg symbol. You can double click the bg object (the big white box) and then drop the wall pieces on the stage. Basically you need to make sure the wall movieClips are children of the bg movieClip.

Also check that the as file you created is set as the document class. You can check that by clicking Window->Properties in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

basically for this to work, the wall movieclips need to be children of the bg movieclip and have the names provided (in this case "wallTop", "wallBottom", "wallRight" and "wallLeft". i'm assuming you're doing this through flash itself (as opposed to doing it through pure code), so double click on the bg movieclip, make sure the walls are in there, click once on them, and make sure their `instance name` is set right.

by having some code `bg.wallTop`, what you're saying is "look in the movieclip 'bg' for the child movieclip 'wallTop'"